# How to print special char in Perl

Tags: perl, escaping

I have a special char in my variable like this

```
my $var = "\n"; 
my $var_tab = "\t";
```

I need to print out not this character but character value/code (\t,\n).
I have tried to add one more slash, but it doesn't work.

```
 my $var.="\\";
```

How can I print value of special char?

Comment: You want the output to be `\t`, right? `"\\t"` should work.

Answer (score 1):

It might help us understand the context if you explained why you want this and what you're trying to achieve.

If you simple want to dump out the value of a variable and have the special characters be visible and readable then perhaps Data::Dumper would help:

```
use Data::Dumper

$var = "\n";
$var_tab = "\t";

$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

print Data::Dumper::qquote($var);      # "\n"
print Data::Dumper::qquote($var_tab);  # "\t"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want print the special character value, Try `regex` for substitute the `\` with empty.Like

```
my $var = "\\n"; 
$var =~s/\\//g;
print "$'";
```

Else If you want print the `\n` . Just use the single quotes instead of double quotes. or use forward slashes within double quotes.

```
my $var = "\\n";   #slashes for escape the special character 
my $var_tab = '\t'; #single quotes also escape the special character
print "$var  $var_tab  ";
```